# Loading XSD Schema within JAR by using Resource fails

Tags: java, jar, xsd

within my jar I am providing my xsd Schema file, ie following structure:

```
myjar
 - myschema.xsd
```

I can verify the file is present at root level inside the JAR when I unzip it.

I am adding the xsd Schema to the SchemaFactory in the following way:

```
public void loadXSDSchema() throws InitializationException {
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    try {
        xsdSchema = sf.newSchema(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(XSD_SCHEMA_FILE).getFile()));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new InitializationException(ApiExceptionId.INIT_XSD_SCHEMA, e);
    }
```

Unfortunately it is not working in the produced JAR file - I am getting a FileNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\dev\myjar.jar!\myschema.xsd (Die Syntax f▒r den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentr▒gerbezeichnung ist falsch)
```

I thought I did know that you need to read it as a Resource when it's packaged inside a jar but reality shows me I seem to be doing something wrong.

Any hints on what I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not get it as a file since it is not a file. It is an entry in your jar file. Files are operating system objects, and from OS point of view the jar file is the file. Although you can get an `InputStream` via `ClassLoader`  and you can read the content of it via this InputStream.

```
Schema xsdSchema = sf.newSchema( new StreamSource(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("shema.xsd")));
```

Comment: Okay, now I see it. I only knew the thing about Resource, but yes that makes a lot of sense thank you!

Comment: Hi in my case need to load an XSD from classpath that <import> other XSDs that are on the classpath too. In this case your piece of code don't work properly because the `sf` schema factory is not able to locate the imported XSDs.

Comment: Sorry, if it does not resolve your problem, but it clearly resolved the original question, so the answer is valid here. Asking your own question might will resolve your problem. Unfortunately I have no idea how to handle embedded xsd references.